# perform an operation for *each* item listed by grep

Tags: bash, list, shell, grep, exec

How can I perform an operation for each item listed by grep individually?

Background:

I use grep to list all files containing a certain pattern:

```
grep -l '<pattern>' directory/*.extension1
```

I want to delete all listed files *but also* all files having the same file name but a different extension: `.extension2`.

I tried using the pipe, but it seems to take the output of grep as a whole.

In find there is the `-exec` option, but grep has nothing like that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If I understand your specification, you want:

```
grep --null -l '<pattern>' directory/*.extension1 | \
    xargs -n 1 -0 -I{} bash -c 'rm "$1" "${1%.*}.extension2"' -- {}
```

This is essentially the same as what @triplee's comment describes, except that it's newline-safe.

### What's going on here?

`grep` with `--null` will return output delimited with nulls instead of newline. Since file names can have newlines in them delimiting with newline makes it impossible to parse the output of `grep` safely, but null is not a valid character in a file name and thus makes a nice delimiter.

`xargs` will take a stream of newline-delimited items and execute a given command, passing as many of those items (one as each parameter) to a given command (or to `echo` if no command is given). Thus if you said:

```
printf 'one\ntwo three \nfour\n' | xargs echo
```

`xargs` would execute `echo one 'two three' four`. This is not safe for file names because, again, file names might contain embedded newlines.

The `-0` switch to `xargs` changes it from looking for a newline delimiter to a null delimiter. This makes it match the output we got from `grep --null` and makes it safe for processing a list of file names.

Normally `xargs` simply appends the input to the end of a command. The `-I` switch to `xargs` changes this to substitution the specified replacement string with the input. To get the idea try this experiment:

```
printf 'one\ntwo three \nfour\n' | xargs -I{} echo foo {} bar
```

And note the difference from the earlier `printf | xargs` command.

In the case of my solution the command I execute is `bash`, to which I pass `-c`. The `-c` switch causes bash to execute the commands in the following argument (and then terminate) instead of starting an interactive shell. The next block `'rm "$1" "${1%.*}.extension2"'` is the first argument to `-c` and is the script which will be executed by `bash`. Any arguments following the script argument to `-c` are assigned as the arguments to the script. This, if I were to say:

```
bash -c 'echo $0' "Hello, world"
```

Then `Hello, world` would be assigned to `$0` (the first argument to the script) and inside the script I could `echo` it back.

Since `$0` is normally reserved for the script name I pass a dummy value (in this case `--`) as the first argument and, then, in place of the second argument I write `{}`, which is the replacement string I specified for `xargs`. This will be replaced by `xargs` with each file name parsed from `grep`'s output before `bash` is executed.

The mini shell script might look complicated but it's rather trivial. First, the entire script is single-quoted to prevent the calling shell from interpreting it. Inside the script I invoke `rm` and pass it two file names to remove: the `$1` argument, which was the file name passed when the replacement string was substituted above, and `${1%.*}.extension2`. This latter is a parameter substitution on the `$1` variable. The important part is `%.*` which says

- `%` "Match from the end of the variable and remove the shortest string matching the pattern.
- `.*` The pattern is a single period followed by anything.

This effectively strips the extension, if any, from the file name. You can observe the effect yourself:

```
foo='my file.txt'
bar='this.is.a.file.txt'
baz='no extension'
printf '%s\n'"${foo%.*}" "${bar%.*}" "${baz%.*}"
```

Since the extension has been stripped I concatenate the desired alternate extension `.extension2` to the stripped file name to obtain the alternate file name.

Comment: this looks good, but can you explain these commands a bit? I also want to learn something :)

Answer (score 4):

If this does what you want, pipe the output through /bin/sh.

```
grep -l 'RE' folder/*.ext1 | sed 's/\(.*\).ext1/rm "&" "\1.ext2"/'
```

Or if sed makes you itchy:

```
grep -l 'RE' folder/*.ext1 | while read file; do
  echo rm "$file" "${file%.ext1}.ext2"
done
```

Remove `echo` if the output looks like the commands you want to run.

But you can do this with `find` as well:

```
find /path/to/start -name \*.ext1 -exec grep -q 'RE' {} \; -print | ...
```

where `...` is either the sed script or the three lines from `while` to `done`.

The idea here is that `find` will ... well, "find" things based on the qualifiers you give it -- namely, that things match the file glob "*.ext", AND that the result of the "exec" is successful.  The `-q` tells grep to look for RE in `{}` (the file supplied by `find`), and exit with a TRUE or FALSE without generating any of its own output.

The only real difference between doing this in find vs doing it with grep is that you get to use find's awesome collection of conditions to narrow down your search further if required.  `man find` for details.  By default, find will recurse into subdirectories.

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe the list to xargs:

```
grep -l '<pattern>' directory/*.extension1 | xargs rm
```

As for the second set of files with a different extension, I'd do this (as usual use `xargs echo rm` when testing to make a dry run; I haven't tested it, it may not work correctly with filenames with spaces in them):

```
filelist=$(grep -l '<pattern>' directory/*.extension1)
echo $filelist | xargs rm
echo ${filelist//.extension1/.extension2} | xargs rm
```

Comment: Provided you don't have any file names with newlines, you could do something like ´grep -l 'pattern' directory/*.extension1 | sed 'p;s/\.extension1$/.extension2/' | xargs rm`

Comment: @tripleee: I agree, that's probably better! I didn't think of it.

Comment: I would be very careful with echoing unquoted expansions and piping to `xargs rm` - chances are you will blow something up unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the result to `xargs`, it will allow you to run a command for each match.