# How to pipe output from grep to cp?

Tags: linux, shell, grep, cp

I have a working `grep` command that selects files meeting a certain condition. How can I take the selected files from the `grep` command and pipe it into a `cp` command?

The following attempts have failed on the `cp` end:

```
grep -r "TWL" --exclude=*.csv* | cp ~/data/lidar/tmp-ajp2/
```

> cp: missing destination file operand after
>   ‘/home/ubuntu/data/lidar/tmp-ajp2/’ Try 'cp --help' for more
>   information.

---

```
cp `grep -r "TWL" --exclude=*.csv*` ~/data/lidar/tmp-ajp2/
```

> cp: invalid option -- '7'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [perform an operation for \*each\* item listed by grep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682721/perform-an-operation-for-each-item-listed-by-grep)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
grep -l -r "TWL" --exclude=*.csv* | xargs cp -t ~/data/lidar/tmp-ajp2/
```

Explanation:

- grep `-l` option to output file names only
- xargs to convert file list from the standard input to command line arguments
- cp  `-t` option to specify target directory (and avoid using placeholders)

Comment: The `-l` option does not work for me. Aside from that, it works fine.

Comment: `-t` is said an illegal option for `cp` on macOS sierra.

Comment: I still had issues with cp using this syntax. Chris Maes solution below worked for me

Comment: Had issues with this answer where the filenames contained spaces.

Comment: Is there a way to use this solution if the file name length is too long for cp?

Answer (score 42):

you need **xargs** with the **placeholder** option:

```
grep -rl "TWL" --exclude=*.csv* | xargs -I '{}' cp '{}' ~/data/lidar/tmp-ajp2/
```

normally if you use `xargs`, it will put the output **after** the command, with the placeholder (`'{}'` in this case), you can choose the location where it is inserted, even multiple times.

Comment: Your answer worked nearly perfectly, yet grep -r raised an error since it passed the entire result (with the line containing the string) to xargs. This issue was solved using with both rl flags, as in: grep -rl '<search_string>' * | xargs -I '{}' cp '{}' <detination_dir>

Comment: @RonyArmon you are completely right. It's a mystery to my why you are the first one to point this error. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me when searching for files with a specific date:

```
 ls | grep '2018-08-22' | xargs -I '{}' cp '{}' ~/data/lidar/tmp-ajp2/
```

Comment: please explain xargs -I '{}' cp '{}' ~/data/lidar/tmp-ajp2/

Comment: @santosh-kumar, the `'{}'` are placeholders for the results of the grep listing `ls | grep`.  So in my case, the command listed all the files that match the given date in their filename, and then copied each file to a specific directory.

Answer (score 1):

To copy files to grep found directories, use -printf to output directories and -i to place the command argument from xarg (after pipe)

```
find ./ -name 'filename.*' -print '%h\n' | xargs -i cp copyFile.txt {}
```

this copies copyFile.txt to all directories (in ./) containing "filename"

Answer (score -1):

grep -rl '/directory/' -e 'pattern' | xargs cp -t /directory

Comment: Would you care to elaborate on that?