# xargs/find/grep a list of files from a list of directories

Tags: bash, grep, find, command-line-interface

I have a list of directories in a text file, wherein I want to find and change files that share a particular naming convention.

**example file:**

```
dir1
dir2
dir3
```

**example folder structure with files**

```
dir1/
   thing.txt
   thing.blah
dir2/
   rar.txt
   thing.blah
dir3/
   apple.txt
   another.text.file.txt
   thing.blah
```

First, I find the name of the .txt, but then I want to perform a change on it. For example, i want to perform a sed command on thing.txt, rar.txt and apple.txt, but not another.text.file.txt.

My question is, once I have all the file names, how do I perform a command on the files with those names? How can I then take those lines of text such as:

```
cat dirFile.txt | xargs ls | grep <expression>.txt 
    thing.txt
    rar.txt
    apple.txt
 !cat | some command
```

and run an action on the actual files under the directories?

What I'm getting is the above result,

But what I need is

```
dir1/thing.txt
dir2/rar.txt
dir3/apple.txt
```

Comment: Why not `another.text.file.txt`?

Comment: what I'm trying to get is file itself in `dir1/thing.txt
dir2/thing.txt` etc, if I could write that to a file, that'd be fine, but I can't figure out how to get which dir which file is in, so that I operate on the correct file. If I could get that list, then I could do it in line anyway, and wouldn't need to write it to a file....

Comment: try using find.  find <dir> -name *.txt > myfilelist

Comment: or find <dir> -regex <regex>.txt > myfilelist

Comment: @user5976242 "**I have a list of directories in a text file**"

Comment: I understood that, OP wanted to use xargs. cat dirs.txt |xarg -I % find % -name *.txt or -regex <exp>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pipe output from grep to cp?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33140583/608639), [Is there a grep equivalent for find's -print0 and xargs's -0 switches?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15976570/608639), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have a file named `dirs` which have all directories you need to search:

```
while IFS= read -r i; do
  find "$i" -name '<expression>' -print0
done < dirs | xargs -0 some_command
```

If you know the directories doesn't have spaces or another type of separators you can simplify a bit:

```
find $(<dirs) -name '<expression>' -print0 | xargs -0 some_command
```

Perhaps your `some_command` expect only one file at a time, in this case use `-n1`:

```
... | xargs -0 -n1 some_command
```

or move `some_command` to find itself:

```
find $(<dirs) -name '<expression>' -exec some_command {} \;
```

- `$(<dirs)` is a [comand substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html#sect_03_04_04). It reads the content (like `cat`) of `dirs` file and use it as the first arguments of `find`. Empty `dirs` is safe on GNU find (eg Linux) but you need at least one line - which is converted as one argument - on BSD (eg Mac OS X)
- `-print0` separates files with `null`
- `-0` expects these `null` chars.
- `-n1` says `xargs` to send only one argument to `some_command`

Comment: that find $(<dirs) is elegant and short. I love it! Can you articulate the behavior? I know it's working, but not how it works. Or do you have any reading that could help me better understand?

I know that $() is a subshell, and that the < is taking dirs as an input, but I don't know what iteration is happening, or how it's taking arguments

Comment: @nanthil no visible iteration here. `$(<dirs)` output the content of `dirs` file just like `cat` do. `find` accept 0..n (GNU) or 1..n (BSD) arguments saying where it should work. I edited the answer with more information.

Answer (score 1):

I guess my comments were not adequately expressed. to get the output you desire;

```
cat dirfile.txt | xargs -I % find % -name <your file spec> or -regex <exp>
```