# mobaXterm copy after grep

Tags: grep, cp, mobaxterm

I am doing

```
grep -l 0000201290 ServerApplication.log* | xargs cp  j231110_4/
```

but it tells me

```
cp: can't stat 'ServerApplication.log.5/j231110_4': Not a directory
```

Which is correct, it should be 'j231110_4/ServerApplication.log.5', because 'j231110_4' is a directory and 'ServerApplication.log.5' is a file I want to be copied in directory 'j231110_4'.

How can I copy grep output list of files to some dir?

Have tried [How to pipe output from grep to cp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33140583/how-to-pipe-output-from-grep-to-cp)  but it does not work.
I guess mobaXterm works differently than linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arguments are ending up in the wrong order. Use [xargs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html)' -I for a placeholder.

```
grep -l 0000201290 ServerApplication.log* | xargs -I@ cp "@" j231110_4/
```

This is pretty forgiving as long as your replacement string doesn't show up anywhere else in your command.

```
$: echo 1 2 3 | xargs -Ibar echo "cp 'bar' foo/"
cp '1 2 3' foo/

$: rm -fr foo/; mkdir -p foo/; touch '1 2 3'; echo 1 2 3 | xargs -Ibar cp 'bar' foo/; ls -l foo/
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 P2759474 1049089 0 Nov 13 08:50 '1 2 3'
```

## ah, BusyBox...

> I get `xargs: unknown option -- I  BusyBox v1.22.1 (2015-11-10 11:07:12    ) multi-call binary.` . . .

Try this then: use `cp`'s `-t` option to make the argument order irrelevant.

```
grep -l 0000201290 ServerApplication.log* | xargs cp -t j231110_4/
```

It *should* work as long as you do NOT have any weird characters like embedded spaces in your filenames - looks likely, but I try to make as few assumptions as possible. I ran a quick test on a HackerRank BusyBox v1.36.1, so hopefully v1.22.1 will respect `-t`.

*If you do* have odd characters... try this.

```
mapfile -t lst < <( grep -l 0000201290 ServerApplication.log* )
cp -t j231110_4/ "${lst[@]}"
```

If none of those work for whatever reason, fall back to simplest:

```
grep -l 0000201290 ServerApplication.log* |
  while read -r file; do cp "$file" j231110_4/; done
```

This will still fail on embedded newlines, so check your data.

Or (again, as long as there are no embedded surprises) just

```
cp $(grep -l 0000201290 ServerApplication.log*) j231110_4/
```

- but be aware of why you are using the versions that aren't *generally* safe. "Convenient" syntax isn't always the best idea.

Comment: then I get `xargs: unknown option -- I`

Comment: Apologies for the short answer and duplicate post before. My phone was misbehaving. Does this example clear up the problem?

Comment: I get `xargs: unknown option -- I 
BusyBox v1.22.1 (2015-11-10 11:07:12    ) multi-call binary.

Usage: xargs [OPTIONS] [PROG ARGS]

Run PROG on every item given by stdin

        -p      Ask user whether to run each command
        -r      Don't run command if input is empty
        -0      Input is separated by NUL characters
        -t      Print the command on stderr before execution
        -e[STR] STR stops input processing
        -n N    Pass no more than N args to PROG
        -s N    Pass command line of no more than N bytes
        -x      Exit if size is exceeded`

Comment: Got `cp: unknown option -- t`, but `while read `... finally worked. Great! Thanks!